# Setting up GMP Library on XCode for C++

Tags: c++, xcode, gmp

I had a question on setting up GMP Library to work on XCode for C++ programming. Although I have tried pursuing the GMP manual and also other similar stack questions on getting the library to work properly, I still have not been able to properly get the library to work. I am new to C++ and programming in general so please bear with me.

Things I have tried:

- Install GMP library through homebrew using `brew install gmp`
- Using the XCode interface under header search paths and library search paths added the path "/usr/local/include" (this is where homebrew installs the gmp library)
- Under other linker flags added `-lgmp` `-lgmpxx`
- Tried running various sample codes e.g.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <gmp.h>
> #include <gmpxx.h>
>
> using namespace std; 
>
> int main ()
> {
>     mpz_t p;
>     mpz_init(p);         
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

However this code fails to compile and the XCode debugger has the following error messages:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
          _main in main.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `-lgmp -lgmpxx` maybe?

Comment: Added -lgmpxx under linker flags, but still received the same error message.

Comment: You can also try `-L/usr/local/lib64  -lgmp -lgmpxx` and as the message says if you add `-v` to see what the compiler is trying to do.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can add `-L/usr/local/lib64 -lgmp -lgmpxx` through XCode by using the linker flags options. However after adding what you suggested, I still don't see any visible change.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it *without* `XCode`? `clang++ -o prog prog.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx`

Comment: After trying `clang++ -o prog prog.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx` I received the error message `main.cpp:12:9: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found'

Comment: `clang++ -o prog prog.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib64 -lgmp -lgmpxx`

Comment: I checked my directory and I don't have /usr/local/lib64. Instead I have a /usr/local/lib address where gmp seems to be installed. I changed lib64 to lib and the complier runs fine. If it isn't too much can you either explain the meaning of clang++ and the following code or link me to a relevant source so I can better understand it? Also is there any reason why the above compiled, but I was unable to complie in XCode?

Comment: All you need to do now is set `XCode` flags the same as you just used on the command line and it *should* work. `clang++` is the compiler. `-I` tells it where to find `#include <>` files and `-L` tells it where to search for libraries.

Comment: Ok. I set the same flags in XCode (under other linker flags) but the same error pops up. However I'm not sure how to include the clang++ option. How does the interaction between clang++ and xcode work?

Comment: `clang++` is not an option its the program that converts your code into a binary executable generally called a 'compiler'. `XCode` is not the compiler but an IDE (editor). It doesn't compile your code it passes it to `clang++`.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you double check that the flag settings in `XCode` are exactly the same as the command line. The linker flags are `-L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lgmpxx`. Don't put any of the other flags in the linker flag section

Comment: `-lgmp` should come **after** `-lgmpxx` on the command line. (that's not the problem here though since you are not using gmpxx)

Comment: @Galik I have exactly the same issue but I have more info: The log says: > ld: library not found for -lgmp